# Нет подключения к серверу

Tags: java, android

извиняюсь за отсутствие кода, если он будет нужен для решения проблемы - предоставлю.

Мною было написано приложение, котое обрабатывает http запросы. Сервер работает прекрасно. В AVD приложение работает корректно. Но после создания APK через `Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s)` и установки его на реальное устройство пропадает подключение к серверу. Вот пример: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucZfJsiuYYo&ab_channel=vasapup .

Хочу заметить что доступ к интернету выдан. Как компьютер так и телефон находятся в одной сети и имеют доступ к интернету.

Моим предположением является отсутствие подписи разработчика.

С чем может быть связано такое поведение приложения после сборки?

**UPD 1**

```
    private void loadStrings()
    {
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url_head = "http://62.113.110.15:8080/rStrings";
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url_head, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    main_id_rSting = new long[response.length()];
                    main_name_rString = new String[response.length()];
                    main_code_rString = new String[response.length()];
                    temp = response.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length();i++){
                        JSONObject string_params_string_list = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        long string_id = string_params_string_list.getLong("id");
                        String string_name = string_params_string_list.getString("name");
                        String string_code = string_params_string_list.getString("code");

                        main_id_rSting[i]=string_id;
                        main_name_rString[i] = string_name;
                        main_code_rString[i] = string_code;

                        Log.i("Id", String.valueOf(main_id_rSting[i]));
                        Log.i("Id", main_name_rString[i]);
                        Log.i("Id", main_code_rString[i]);
                        Log.i("Id", String.valueOf(main_id_rSting.length));
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() { // в случае возникновеня ошибки
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TimeoutError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NoConnectionError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AuthFailureError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //TODO
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ServerError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //TODO
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NetworkError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //TODO
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ParseError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //TODO
                }
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: вообще для того, чтобы работало http без SSL сейчас надо давать еще одно доп разрешение. но как тогда она запустилось на эмуляторе?   `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: В этом то и загвоздка. AVD работает прекрасно, а вот телефон отказывается работать. Причем я проверял на разных устройствах.

Comment: Есть ошибка, если не даёт соединения. Приведите эту ошибку

Comment: Только что перепроверил, это `NoConnectionError`

Comment: а с телефона в браузере можете открыть эту url ?

Comment: Да, в видосе открывал. Нормально все работает.

Comment: http://62.113.110.15:8080/rStrings вот по этому URL делается get запрос.

Comment: Так подключите телефон к AS и запустите в режиме отладки, посмотрите Logcat и многое прояснится. Смысл гадать на кофейной гуще по видео?

Comment: Код подключения покажите

Comment: @ArtyMorris, обновил.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja кажется я понял в чем ошибка. `W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 62.113.110.15 not permitted`

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja и @Wlad спасибо огромное. Про `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` сначала не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что с версии Android 9 нельзя передавать открытый HTTP текст. Чтобы исправить данную ошибку нужно прописать в файле `AndroidManifests.xml` следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" //Эту строчку нужно дописать
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

И все заработает.

Comment: Так делать не стоит. Пройдите codelab https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config

Comment: Я понимаю что так делать не стоит, но для моих целей это и не нужно.

Comment: А вы ответ здесь публикуете для собственных нужд?